# How do I fix a HTTP Error 400: Bad Request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bad-request

I am trying to web scrape, here is my code.

For some reason I am getting HTTP Error 400: Bad Request, I have never had this before.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = ('https://www.myvue.com/whats-on')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

def main():

    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

    content=html_page.decode(errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8')

    headings = re.findall('<th scope="col" abbr="(.*?)">', content)

    print(headings)

main()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix your header:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

It's `User-Agent`, not `User Agent`.

---

Additionally, I would recommend switching over to the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.

```
import requests
html_page = requests.get(url, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
```

This is the equivalent of three lines of `urllib` and much more readable. In addition, it automatically decodes the content for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have got rid of the HTTP Error 400, but the code is not running my regex for some reason, only returning '[ ]'. Sorry for the questions! Only just learning!

Comment: @Jdsmith That's a different question, and deserves another post. Mark this accepted, close it, and open a new one :)

Comment: @Jdsmith Also, as a quick side note, I strongly recommend you look at [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Yes, I have done beautiful soup, but wanted to try another way! Thanks

Comment: Hi @COLDSPEED , Do you have any ideas for my most recent question?