# Python Requests POST - error 400

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this code:

```
import requests
import json 

data={"client_id" : "a", "client_secret" : "thisissecret", "grant_type" : "clientcredentials", "scope" : "PublicApi"}

url = 'http://MYURL/connect/token'
response = requests.post(url, json=data, verify=False)
print(response)
print response.reason
print(response.json())
```

I'm trying to test connection to a new auth service in test environment (which is why verify is FALSE) This should give me the access token and the token type and with them I can POST to the API.

But I always get:

```
<Response [400]>  Bad Request   {u'error': u'invalid_request'}
```

I'm not sure what is the problem?
Why is it a bad request?

Comment: If possible post the 'http://MYURL/connect/token' endpoint code

Comment: @RanaAhmed Hi, the url itself is OK. I tested the same request with PostMan https://www.getpostman.com/ and it worked. I suspect this is something to do with how I built this code...

Comment: This might work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058650/4909087

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to change `json=data` to `json=json.dumps(data)` but call `import json` first.

Comment: @coldspeed same error still appear

Comment: Did you try the recommendations in the link I shared as well?

Comment: @coldspeed: `requests`will take care of dumping the json for you, no need to do it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to obtain an OAuth 2.0 access token using the client_credientials grant. This is [described in RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2)

I see 2 problems here:

- You must post your fields as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `json`. To do so, use the `data` parameter of `request.post()` instead of `json`
- The `grant_type` value must be `client_credentials` instead of `clientcredentials`

Which gives:

```
import requests

data = {"client_id" : "a", "client_secret" : "thisissecret", 
        "grant_type" : "client_credentials", "scope" : "PublicApi"}

url = 'http://MYURL/connect/token'
response = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False)
if response.ok:
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 13, in <module>
    if response.is_ok:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'is_ok'

Comment: typo, fixed now

Comment: Awesome! it works. How do I access the info inside the response.json?

Comment: `response.json()` returns a standard Python dict (which is the result of parsing the JSON response), so you can read it just like a dict (e.g: to get the access token: `at = response.json()['access_token']`)

Comment: Thank you! I would do +1 but I dont have sufficient rank.

Comment: BTW - say respond.ok is not True. What try catch I should use here? What exception will it raise?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set the content type of the header?

```
import requests
import json 

data={"client_id" : "a", "client_secret" : "thisissecret", "grant_type" : "clientcredentials", "scope" : "PublicApi"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

url = 'http://MYURL/connect/token'
response = requests.post(url, json=data, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

Comment: `requests` will take care of that for you when you use `json={"your":"data"}` parameter to `requests.post()`

Comment: Didn't know that. From: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/ `Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to application/json.`